# How to add to_sentence to a :collection

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, collections

I have the following code that generates a list of superlatives:

```
<%= render :partial => 'superlative', :collection => @profile.superlatives %>
```

The `:partial` code referenced above is as follows:

```
<li class="superlative"><span title="<%= superlative.name %>">
  <%= superlative.body %>
</span></li>
```

How can I add `to_sentence` to the @profile.superlatives collection? I tried:

```
<%= render :partial => 'superlative', :collection => @profile.superlatives.to_sentence %>
```

Doing so however makes the @profile.superlatives disappear from the view.

I looked at the docs but couldn't find an answer.

Comment: I'm not sure what your question is. Rails makes `to_sentence` available on all arrays. Are you seeing issues when you call `@profile.superlatives.to_sentence`?

Comment: Yeah, for some reason `<%= render :partial => 'superlative', :collection => @profile.superlatives.to_sentence %>` in my `show.html.erb` removes the `@profile.superlatives` from the view.

Comment: I'm still confused. What do you want the ultimate output to look like? Are you trying to render a list (`<li>...`), which is what your partial does, or are you trying to render a sentence?

Comment: Ah, gotcha. I'm trying to render a list of superlatives where the superlatives are separated by ", ". Ideally it would have something like `:last_word_connector` where the last superlative doesn't have a comma and space after it.

Comment: So what's the partial for? Just use `<%= @profile.superlatives.to_sentence %>`.

Comment: Doing that renders `#<Superlative:0x10f7b0808>, #<Superlative:0x10f7a6f10>,...` Sorry for all this, I'm a beginner.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ohhh, now I understand. Sorry for the confusion. Here's what I would do:

In your controller:

```
@superlative_bodies = @profile.superlatives.map &:body
# Equivalent to: @superlative_bodies = @profile.superlatives.map {|sup| sup.body }
```

In your view:

```
= @superlative_bodies.to_sentence
```

Some people would do this all in the view instead, which is up to you:

```
= @profile.superlatives.map(&:body).to_sentence
```

To explain, `.map` is a super-useful Ruby method that takes an array or other Enumerable and a block and returns a new array where each element is the corresponding element from the original array after the block has been applied to it. For example:

```
[ 'foo', 'bar', 'baz' ].map {|word| word.upcase } # => [ 'FOO', 'BAR', 'BAZ' ]
# or
[ 'foo', 'bar', 'baz' ].map &:upcase              # => [ 'FOO', 'BAR', 'BAZ' ]
```

(The latter is just a shortened version of the former for when you only want to call the same single method on every element.)

Comment: Sorry, one last thing: this outputs a sentence. Is there a way to output each superlative.body as an <li> element? So it's a list of elements separated by commas.

Comment: No, not with `to_sentence`. To do that I would use a partial like in your question but also pass in @profile.superlatives.length as a local, then use that and `superlative_counter` to decide whether to print a comma or "and." http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#local-variables

Answer (score 1):

Something like this, perhaps?

```
module ProfilesHelper
  # ...
  def superlatives_items (profile)
    @@acb ||= ActionController::Base.new # required to access render_to_string
    profile.superlatives.collect |superlative|
      acb.render_to_string :partial => 'path/to/partial/superlative',
                           :layout => false,
                           :locals => { :superlative => superlative }
    end
  end
  # ...
end

# In view:

# <%= raw(superlatives_items(@profile).to_sentence) %>
```